# A suggestion followed by a link; flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I've been actively flagging VLQ answers in "problematic" tags lately. Today I noticed that a few of my flags were declined because *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*.

Here's one of the flagged posts (an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5931652/2301450) question):

[image]

It was noted in comments that the link is no longer working and its absence rendered this answer useless. On the other hand, the accepted answer is elaborate and correct.

And here's another one (an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18826168/2301450) question):

[image]

These answers are quite similar: they both suggest approaches that could possibly work (without caring for further explanation) and link to possibly relevant off-site resources. What's the policy for such answers?

Comment: Neither of those answers are "Very Low Quality". Very Low Quality means the post is unredeemable, is completely crap, and should be deleted by a moderator immediately.  In neither case is that true.

Comment: @davidism - the correct response here is down-vote and/or edit.

Comment: @davidism Downvote it; and then get three of your friends to help you delete it if you have over 10K reputation. No need for a moderator to immediately intervene here.

Comment: I'd always believed that VLQ/NAA flags go to VLQ posts queue and not directly to mods.

Comment: @vaultah - They do, but if they're not acted on by that queue in a timely manner (currently after an hour), they end up in the moderator flag queue. The fact that you cast ~70 of these in the last five hours probably overflowed the ability of the review queue to handle them quickly, and many of these started appearing in the moderator flag queue.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson, it's clear now. I suppose the solution is to flag less/less frequently and/or ensure that even mods would accept the flag?

Comment: @vaultah - You had identified a bunch of really terrible posts in there which we took care of. These few, though, didn't seem to us to warrant immediate deletion. It's just a handful out of the bunch.

Comment: @davidism Nothing; I just undeleted it. Thanks for catching that.  I focused on the link part and didnt' see the rest. tunnel vision.

Comment: @davidism Instead of keeping quiet and not letting me realize my mistake, you called me on it and I corrected it. Let that be a lesson, never interrupt your enemy while they're making a mistake (h/t to Sun Tzu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the links from both of those. How do they read?

> You can do it using inner join.

and

> It's possible using GridLayout.

There's more to those answers than just a link. I'll admit, not a lot more, but there is content beyond the links that could possibly answer the question asked.

They don't warrant immediate deletion by a moderator, in my opinion.

Comment: But what to do with such questions? When I chose "No action needed" on such questions, review audit said "It was a test, you didn't pass". Just downvote, as George Stocker proposed?