# Why was my answer converted into a comment?

Tags: discussion

Someone asked this good question - [How to write long messy text to database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50100382/939213) . They were downvoted and told this was a bad question. They then added superfluous information and got upvoted.

I posted an answer (before their edit) which OP accepted and commented that it helped them. My answer was downvoted, of course. I got upvoted later. (Perhaps after the answer was accepted?) The answer was: letting OP know of Parameterized Queries which OP wasn't aware existed.

The question got closed as a duplicate, and though the 'duplicate' has an answer similar to mine, *the question* is not a duplicate. Someone mentioned that in the comments as well.

Now a moderator came around and converted the answer into a comment so future readers won't be able to find the answer unless they search the comments.

(This action also deleted the question, which then hid some useful information in the comments there regarding the dangers of posting confidential information in questions. People might think, incorrectly, that if they change their minds, they'll be able to delete it later.)

For those of you with less than 10k rep, the answer (as a comment) is here: [How to write long messy text to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100382/how-to-write-long-messy-text-to-database/50100448#comment87238791_50100382)  .

**EDIT**

The answer got undeleted and I now updated it. I hope it's to everyone's satisfaction.

Comment: Beyond the multiple downvotes on the post, it no doubt got flagged by several users.  Your response to Nigel's comment indicated that you had no interest in improving the post.  That leaves few alternatives, converting short posts that are nothing but a collection of links to a comment is a decent way for a mod can rescue the info.  I have seen plenty of answers on the many questions you asked, posted some myself.  They never looked like that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm grateful for all of your answers to my questions. Also, for your answers to others' questions which I was helped by. I was trying to do the same thing and help someone. Unfortunately I don't know as much as you and so couldn't post a complete answer with code without investing some time to make sure I'm not wasting OP's time with incorrect code. Time I didn't have while posting my answer. I admit the answer would have been better with more explanation.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the answer there (it was undeleted). I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because your answer is basically:

> *"Use <Technology>, look at this Stack Overflow answer.
>
>   Also look at this other answer"*

[image]

That's barely an answer. A comment is a better fit.

Remove all the links. Remove all the references to other SO answers, all that remains is:

> You use a Parameterized Query.

That doesn't answer the question any more than *"Use Regexes"* would. Sure, it's a push in the right direction, but those belong in comments.

Comment: No. My answer is: Use parameterized queries. OP should be able to find _how_ to use them on their own, now that they know what to look for. I just helped them along.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290368/2301450. It may be a poor answer, but it's still an answer.

Comment: @ispiro: That's only 24% of the answer's length, and makes the question a duplicate. _"Helping them along"_ isn't an answer. It's a prod in the right direction. If anything, I don't think it's enough to warrant undeleting the answer.

Comment: Of course "Helping them along" isn't an answer. That's not my point. My point is that an answer is an answer if it answers the question. The length of the answer is irrelevant (if it answers the question).

Comment: @ispiro: And my point is that it doesn't answer the question. It's a helpful suggestion, but no more than that. In the end, nothing of value was really lost. The suggestion still exists in the comments, and the question is closed as a duplicate, as it should be.

Comment: How does it not answer the question? OP didn't know how to sanitize a query. Now they know what they need to use. You want us spoonfeeding askers? (And look at OP's response. I think they were happy with it.)

Comment: Actually, it _does_ answer the question... The question is _"How do I insert this string full of problematic characters into the database?"_ and the answer is _"Use a parameterized query."_ How does that not answer the question?

Comment: The irony here is that you're asking me to elaborate on my answer...

Comment: Not at all. I only demand that you agree with me :) [that was intended as humor. Just making sure I'm not misunderstood here.] Anyway, I guess we just have to leave this as a disagreement. Cheers!

Comment: @Kendra: The same way _"Use a regex"_ doesn't answer _"How do I find all numbers in this string?"_ It's a pointer in the right direction, no more than that.

Comment: From [Shog9's guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/318307): _"See, this is an answer: `You probably want a FileOutputStream`"_

Comment: No, in this case, it _is_ the correct answer. To insert that statement, especially safely, you use parameters. I looked at the question, I see the answer thanks to your image, and yes, the OP of this question posted the correct answer to _that_ question. Not only that, if it was wrong, it is _an_ answer. We don't delete answers just because they're wrong.

Comment: @ispiro: That I can agree with :-)

Comment: @AndrewMyers: Shog9 isn't always right ;-)

Comment: And really, your "regex" answer example is _also_ an answer. A good answer? Not at all. But it _is an answer._

Comment: @AndrewMyers See the highly upvoted disagreeing comments there. I think the upvotes for that answer are due to the rest of the answer - the original issue there is a link-only answer. That's different.

Comment: Look, I'm just elaborating on what most likely motivated the moderator to ___convert___ the answer to a comment (nothing was _deleted_). I don't think this requires an in-depth analysis. It's just a one-liner that was converted. _*Shrug*_

Comment: @Cerbrus *An answer to the question* being a one line answer doesn't mean it should be a comment.  Length doesn't determine whether something is or is not an answer.  Comments aren't the place for short answers, they're a place for clarifications of a post, which this is not.  The fact that you even say yourself that it's an answer in your meta answer demonstrates that deletion isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy: Yea, that's been said and answered in the comments here, already. As I said, _"I'm just elaborating on what most likely motivated the moderator to convert the answer to a comment."_

Comment: @Cerbrus You felt the need to repeat yourself that short answers should be deleted, so I felt the need to repeat the statement that that's completely wrong, answers are deleted when *they aren't answers*, not when you think they're *short answers*.  Note how there isn't a "this answer is too short" flag, there's just a "Not An Answer" flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus If you're correct that that was the justification, then that justification was wrong, and it should be reversed.

Comment: @Servy: You don't need to tell me. As far as I'm concerned, there isn't anything that needs more discussion, here. This is probably the reasoning behind the move, and that's that. _*Shrug*_

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Sorry you got some flak for explaining someone else's motives (you might also agree with them, but that's not the point).

Answer (score 17):

> Someone asked this good question

No, they didn't. At the time you answered, the question [literally was this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50100382/1):

> Hi I want to take some long messed up string and basically dump it in a string database field. the problem is i get all kinds of problems with the text messing up the insert query. Is there any way i can just ignore the contents and write the whole text without worrying about whats in it?

That's [not a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

> They were downvoted and told this was a bad question. That's unfair.

No, that's fair.

> They then added superfluous information

No, they turned their question into a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in other words, they made their question answerable.

> the question is not a duplicate

It is.

> I also lost the reputation I gained by the answer. Which is also unfair.

It isn't. You shouldn't post poor answers to poor questions. Your answer definitely technically is an answer (*"You should use parameterized queries"*), but when literally posted as an answer (sans the links) that's not necessarily a good answer.